# Clockworkmod Tether fails on "libncurses.so.5"

Tags: 32bit-64bit

While trying to install the Clockworkmod Tether app on Linux, I get the following error;

`adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the 32-bit version of the ncurses library.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5
```